# Action on second button click

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, target-action

I want to make a button invisible on the SECOND click.
I've got an other action on the first click.
How should I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now have you tried doing it?

Comment: I tried but I'm a beginner an now I am kind of desperate.

Comment: Please share what you have tried already. So we know you have made some effort in trying to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either keep state (i.e. count the button clicks) and hide the button on the 2nd click:

```
@interface MyClass ()
{
    NSUInteger _clickCount;
}

- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender
{
   _clickCount++;
   if (_clickCount >= 2) {
        [sender setHidden:YES];
   }
}
```

or you could re-assign the action method in the first click:

```
- (IBAction)firstClick:(id)sender
{
    [sender addTarget:self
               action:@selector(secondClick:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (IBAction)secondClick:(id)sender
{
    [sender setHidden:YES];
}
```

I like the latter approach better.